# how to Create log file for all commands in one file using python

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

```
import subprocess

print("Starting the PMAX Lun-Allocation scrict using Python............")
#step1
sid = (input("Please enter the Array SID:"))
prebackup = (input("Please enter the backup which is to backed up before the process:"))
print(f"Starting the backup Command is : symaccess -sid {sid} -f {prebackup}")
command1 = ("symaccess -sid {sid} -f {prebackup} backup")
process = subprocess.run(command1, shell=True)
command1

#step2
print(f"Listing the all availble devices for sid {sid}............")
listfile = (input("Please enter the text file name where the list of Luns should be stored"))
print(f"Starting the listing Command is : symdev -sid {sid} list -all > {listfile}")
command2=(f"symdev -sid {sid} list -all > {listfile}")
process = subprocess.run(command2, shell=True)
command2

#step3
print("creating Tdev")
tdevfile = (input("Please enter Tdev file name:"))
print(f"Running Command : symconfigure -sid {sid} -f {tdevfile} preview -v")
command3 =(f"symconfigure -sid {sid} -f {tdevfile} preview -v")
process = subprocess.run(command3, shell=True)
command3
```

**Need to create log file in same directory with date for all process output**

can you please help me with this problem I could not able to capture output in file but all output is showing in Shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using print, you can use logger. You can view the output in console and  at the same time, Log will datewise will be generated in Log folder.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers as handlers
import subprocess
import datetime
import os

logger = logging.getLogger("PMAX-Lun-Allocation")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


# maintains log file here  # maintains log file here
Log = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "Log")
if not os.path.exists(Log):
    os.mkdir(Log)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# logHandler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(Log, datetime.datetime.now(
# ).strftime('log_file_%Y_%m_%d.log')), when='midnight', backupCount=10)
logHandler = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    os.path.join(Log, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("log_file_%Y_%m_%d.log")),
    maxBytes=5000000,
    backupCount=10,
)
logHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


# create a logging format
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s: [%(thread)d]:[%(name)s]: %(levelname)s:[PMAX-Lun-Allocation] - %(message)s"
)
logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to the logger

logger.addHandler(logHandler)
logger.addHandler(ch)


logger.debug("Starting the PMAX Lun-Allocation scrict using Python............")
# step1
sid = input("Please enter the Array SID:")
prebackup = input("Please enter the backup which is to backed up before the process:")
logger.debug(f"Starting the backup Command is : symaccess -sid {sid} -f {prebackup}")
command1 = "symaccess -sid {sid} -f {prebackup} backup"
process = subprocess.run(command1, shell=True)
command1

# step2
logger.debug(f"Listing the all availble devices for sid {sid}............")
listfile = input(
    "Please enter the text file name where the list of Luns should be stored"
)
logger.debug(
    f"Starting the listing Command is : symdev -sid {sid} list -all > {listfile}"
)
command2 = f"symdev -sid {sid} list -all > {listfile}"
process = subprocess.run(command2, shell=True)
command2

# step3
logger.debug("creating Tdev")
tdevfile = input("Please enter Tdev file name:")
logger.debug(f"Running Command : symconfigure -sid {sid} -f {tdevfile} preview -v")
command3 = f"symconfigure -sid {sid} -f {tdevfile} preview -v"
process = subprocess.run(command3, shell=True)
command3
```